# Audio web player on python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, аудио, mediaplayer

Решил написать опять вопрос но более конкретно, надеюсь вы поможете.

Хочу написать Audio Web player на python, но нигде не нахожу информации об этом.
Видел много реализаций и примеров на js, прям весь интернет переполнен, но нужно реализовать это на python (xhtml, html, css).

Неужели это невозможно и нету умельцев и умников, что могли бы помочь?

Любая информация будет очень полезной, даже аргументы против.